# Caching issue for Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Problem: Change does not reflect immediately in chatbot iframe on publishing it in amazon lex console against an alias (I have checked that chatbot alias is pointing the correct version and using the same alias only it is deployed in lex-web-ui).

Description:
A lex chatbot is deployed using lex-web-ui and embedded as an iframe on a website.
Steps:

1. I opened the website on a google chrome/cognito or microsoft edge/edge private window and tested a bot and Its working fine
2. One of the intent of my bot have 5 slots asking 5 questions.
3. Now there is a task according to which one specific question needs to be removed from that intent.
4. So I deleted the slot pointing to that particular question, saved the intent, build the bot and published it against the same alias. Also checked in the setting, the alias was pointing to the latest version.

EXPECTATIONS- On refreshing the application in google chrome/incognito or edge/private window the published change should immediately reflect.

OBSERVATIONS:-

1. After refreshing the application and opening the chatbot, we could not find any change that was published in lex console, (it still ask 5 questions whereas it was suppose to ask only 4). In order to reflect those change in iframe i need to clear cache
2. But this is not a case when we use chatbot as a standalone project. As soon the change is published, after refreshing the standalone chatbot those changes are visible, means instead of 5 questions it asks 4 (no need to clear caches)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have updated the question. Please have a look and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache invalidation is to ensure that any changes to the presentation layer (web-ui) are correctly reflected in the client's browser. Lex itself is not cached by CloudFront so the invalidation has no impact on Lex (so long as you're pointing to the same bot and alias combination.

You can safely publish your Lex changes without needing to run cache invalidations.

Comment: I have published the changes and i need to clear website caches in order to reflect that changes. Is there any way that it should reflect on the website without clearing caches?

Comment: You don't need to clear a Cloudfront cache for Lex changes to reflect. Are you certain that the web-ui is pointing to an alias? Confirm that you're publishing to the same alias.

Comment: Yes it is pointing to the same alias on which i have published the changes. The issue is getting resolved if we just go the browser and clear cookies/caches, but what i want is without clearing cookies/caches, those published changes should reflect in borwser

Comment: Your UI is probably caching which is why invalidations are working - do you invalidate the UI cache?

Comment: No I am not invalidating the UI caches specifically, just making clloudfront invalidation with wildcard entry (/*)

Comment: @Reegz I found a behaviour, when I open chatbot as a standalone I can see the changes as soon as i published it in lex console without clearing the caches. But when I open the chatbot as iframe I could not see those changes and needs to clear caches. Do i need to write some js/html tags in chatbot code in order to resolve this? Found this idea from google. And obviously thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Is there any other better approach than the one which i mentioned in above comment. Can you please guide me. And also thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Yes, it’s probably iFrame URL caching - just don’t use an iFrame in 2021 is the best solution :)

Comment: @KaranKatle - something is amiss. Could you try testing this in an incognito browser and without running a cache invalidation? Could you perhaps expand on what you see being cached in terms of Lex? Is it the output, utterances? What specifically is not reflecting on the browser once you've published in Lex?

Comment: @Reegz I tried in incognito browser, same issue. I guess the contents inside the lex-web-ui is getting caches. Yes utterances only. Firstly bot was asking 5 questions, i made a change in console by deleting one slot and it should ask now only 4 questions. But in lex iframe still the bot ends up asking 5 questions only unless we clear the caches of the browser. But if we use chatbot as a standalone project then it doesn't require any browser cache clearing thing, the change immediately reflects after publishing in standalone project.

Comment: @Reegz I have updated the question in detailed manner. Please have a look in it. The reason why i am asking it is once chatbot is live then if any change made in aws lex console will not reflect to the end user unless they clear there caches and we cannot ask all end users to clear cache once the product goes live right?

Comment: Hi @KaranKatle - thanks for expanding. Makes the picture clearer. What is your session expiry time? Perhaps drop that down to, say, 2 minutes? I'm wondering whether your issue is related to a long session lifetime. Lex ensures that a user remains chatting to the same version of a bot for the entire duration of the session. 
So if you're publishing a new version to the existing alias, an in-progress chat would not reflect that change until the session ends and a new one begins.
Please try that and let's see.

Comment: @KaranKatle - have you been able to resolve this? Did the session time change work?

Comment: @Reegz, hey yaah that was helpful, I was able to fix the issue. My chatbot session expiry timing was 24 hours, i reduced it to 5 mins. Thanks for the information

Comment: Hi @KaranKatle - great stuff! Please mark up the specific comment that assisted. Thank you